# Dynamic menu, "move repeaters around"

Tags: asp.net

I am currently developing a blog for myself and my friends, (with some special features, why i am not using those free blogs)
As all blogs there is a left (or right) menu where you can find for example: presentation, blog archive, 10 last blog entries, 10 last comments, images, links, etc.

Every user can change the menu, and order each item as they want to.

But I dont know how to do this in the correct way.

At the moment I create new `div`s and use a `for each` to add `.innerHtml` content.
I guess this is not the best way...

Is there a way to change position of repeaters, or panels on a page?
Or is there some other ways to do this?

----Edit:----

I got one minus for this post so I guess I have to explain my problem a bit more!?

The code for the "menu to the left" is put inside the masterpage.
And I have a lot of functions that create each part of the menu.

```
createShortPresentation();
create10LastPosts();
create10lastComments();
...
```

And instead of using repeaters which I would use if the order of each menu item (presentation, image, 10 last posts.....) was static I just use one panel for the left menu. And that panel I fill with html by each of the functions. The ID of the panel for the left menu is: `leftMenuDiv`

For example, the `create10LastPosts()`, where `last10PostsData` is datatable from database.

```
leftMenuDiv.innerHtml +="<div class="last10Posts">";

for each last10PpostsData
{
    leftMenuDiv.innerHtml += "Name of the post & href and stuff to create the link";
}

leftMenuDiv.innerHtml += "</div>";
```

I dont like this approach, and would like to use repeaters instead, but then I have to put them in an static order.

What should I do?

Any questions?! Please reply if there is something missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating each "menu to the left" element into a separate user control (which will allow you to use repeaters). Then depending on what the order of the menus are, you can dynamically load each user control into a placeholder. Is this the direction you want to go?

Comment: I'm going to try this! Thanks!